# PDF designing using XSL FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a question regarding the PDF designing:

I have a requirement where in the whole PDF should have an image (kind of a background image) along with the header and footer repeating if the content in the body region overflows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this needs some clarification. Exactly what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

For FOP you should check following:

1. Background image you should use 'XSL Formatter V4.3 Extensions', please refer http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf4-extension.htm#axf.background-image
2. For repeated header and footer check http://www.learn-xsl-fo-tutorial.com/Formatting-Objects-Basics.cfm#h1.4